# Best practice for building Docker image in Go multi-module workspace?

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, monorepo, workspace

I have a Go multi-module workspace, following the official [guide](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces). It's really nice since it allows different apps or services to share common libraries/utils without having to publish it. The current project directory is like the following (simplified)

```
workspace
│
├── libs          // common shared functions
│      ├── utils
│      │      └── utils.go
│      │
│      ├── other-utils
│      │      └── other-utils.go
│      │
│      └── go.mod
│
├── services
│      ├── user
│      │      ├── main.go
│      │      ├── go.mod
│      │      └── go.sum
│      │
│      └── article
│             ├── main.go
│             ├── go.mod
│             └── go.sum
├── .dockerignore           
├── go.work
└── go.work.sum
```

This is my current Dockerfile for building the `user` service.

```
FROM golang:1.19-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /workspace
COPY . .

WORKDIR /workspace/services/user
RUN go mod download
RUN go build -o /user-service


FROM alpine:3.17
COPY --from=build /user-service /user-service
ENTRYPOINT ["/user-service"]
```

Now my question is, what's the best practice for building each `service`? In the `COPY . .` step, any changes in other service will invalidate the Docker build cache, causing all the steps from it onwards to re-run. But at the same time, seems that Go workspace can only work when it has all the workspace files in the directory.

I tried just copying `libs` and `services/user` in the Dockerfile, but the build fails at `RUN go build -o /user-service` with the error

```
go: open /workspace/services/article/go.mod: no such file or directory
```

I believe there should be a better solution where we can use the Go workspace and build each service independent of other service changes? Something like resolving all the dependencies upfront before copying the application code.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?
I have a similar architecture and I don't want to release my libs module. I would want the services to refer to the latest libs code but be able to build the services into different Docker containers.

Comment: @ananth As a matter of fact I did, but it's not exactly a solution and more of a workaround. What I did was I prepared a separate `go.work` file that only contains the common libs and the service that I want to build. Then in the Dockerfile, I copied that `go.work` file instead. This way, inside the Docker image build point of view, it looks as if the Go workspace is only the common libs and that service I'm building.